# R {animation} package [saveGIF] - want to use magick instead of convert

Tags: r, animation

I want to make a GIF animation file from a series of R plots. I installed ImageMagick and "animation" package to do this.

I want to use `saveGIF` function, but when I uses the function, it tries to use `convert.exe` in ImageMagick and gives an error. It looks like the current version of ImageMagick uses `magick.exe` instead of `convert.exe` (`convert.exe` does not exist).

I was able to make a GIF animation directly from ImageMagick using `magick.exe` without using the animation package. But it is more convenient for me if I can make saveGIF to use `magick.exe` instead of `convert.exe`. I want to know how to do it.

Installing an older version of ImageMagick that still uses `convert.exe` would solve the problem, but this is not an answer I am looking for.

## UPDATE

I tried `ani.options` suggested by Josh O'Brien. Below is what I got. Not sure what the problem is...

```
> ani.options(convert = 'C:/Program Files/ImageMagick-7.0.5-Q16/magick.exe')
> 
> saveGIF(
+ for(i in 1:10){
+ plot(i,1,xlim=c(0,11))
+ }
+ )
Executing: 
"C:/Program Files/ImageMagick-7.0.5-Q16/magick.exe -loop 0 -delay 100 Rplot1.png Rplot2.png Rplot3.png Rplot4.png Rplot5.png Rplot6.png Rplot7.png
    Rplot8.png Rplot9.png Rplot10.png "animation.gif""
'C:/Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
an error occurred in the conversion... see Notes in ?im.convert
[1] FALSE
Warning messages:
1: running command 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /c "C:/Program Files/ImageMagick-7.0.5-Q16/magick.exe -loop 0  -delay 100 Rplot1.png Rplot2.png Rplot3.png Rplot4.png Rplot5.png Rplot6.png Rplot7.png Rplot8.png Rplot9.png Rplot10.png "animation.gif""' had status 1 
2: In cmd.fun(convert) :
  '"C:/Program Files/ImageMagick-7.0.5-Q16/magick.exe -loop 0  -delay 100 Rplot1.png Rplot2.png Rplot3.png Rplot4.png Rplot5.png Rplot6.png Rplot7.png Rplot8.png Rplot9.png Rplot10.png "animation.gif""' execution failed with error code 1
3: running command '"C:/Program Files/ImageMagick-7.0.5-Q16/magick.exe -loop 0  -delay 100 Rplot1.png Rplot2.png Rplot3.png Rplot4.png Rplot5.png Rplot6.png Rplot7.png Rplot8.png Rplot9.png Rplot10.png "animation.gif""' had status 127
```

Comment: Have you tried fixing the path to the executable using something like `ani.options(convert = '/path/to/magick.exe')` ?

Comment: @Josh O'Brien Thank you. It worked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Josh O'Brien's answer worked. "Program Files" had to be changed to "PROGRA~1".

```
ani.options(convert = 'C:/PROGRA~1/ImageMagick-7.0.5-Q16/magick.exe')

saveGIF(
for(i in 1:10){
plot(i,1,xlim=c(0,11))
}
)
```

Comment: it worked for me. The key was change to "PROGRA~1" instead of "Program Files"