# Create GIF or video from external jpg in R

Tags: r, video, gif

I wanted to do something I thought simple, but... well, I failed repetitively.

I want to create a gif or a video (.avi) from pictures in a folder with R.
I can list the path and the names of the pictures (e.g. "./folder/1.jpg" "./folder/2.jpg" "./folder/3.jpg" "./folder/4.jpg" )

I just wanted to put them the one after the other and create a video or gif file (I will treat them frame by frame later, so the speed is not important)

I found a solution with [SaveGIF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43568632/r-animation-package-savegif-want-to-use-magick-instead-of-convert), it works with plots in R but I didn't find the way to use it with external jpg.

Otherwise, there was this solution with [image_animate](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/magick/vignettes/intro.html) "Animated graphics", but again, I didn't manage.

Do somebody already have a solution to do that?
Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: I'd recommend you use a tool more suited for the task; `ffmpeg` for video, `imagemagick` or `gifsicle` for GIF. All are well documented.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it with the `magick` package, which gives you access to ImageMagick functions.  For example, if the frames of your movie are in files named

```
frames <- paste0("folder/", 1:100, ".jpg")
```

then you would create a movie using

```
library(magick)
m <- image_read(frames)
m <- image_animate(m)
image_write(m, "movie.gif")
```

You could choose to write to other formats as well, just by changing the filename, or using other arguments to `image_write()`.

Comment: That is exactly what I needed!
Unfortunately, the process is horribly long for me. I will have to find another way. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

A better solution in my oppinion is using the `av` package.

example:

```
list_of_frames <- list.files("your/path/to/directory", full.names=T)
av::av_encode_video(list_of_frames, framerate = 30,
                    output = "output_animation.mp4")
```